# Error when doing apt-get update

Tags: debian, apt

I'm using Debian stable and when I use `sudo apt-get update`, I get this message at the end:

```
The AppStream system cache was updated, but some errors were detected, which might lead to missing metadata. Refer to the verbose log for more information.
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I don't know what that means and I want to fix it.